# How to put not parse some markup tags inside CDATA

Tags: xml, text, formatting, cdata, richtext

How would I output something like this inside CDATA: `<b>**bold text**</b>`?

The following didn't work:

```
<![CDATA[&lt;b><b>bold text</b>&lt;/b>]]>
```

`&lt;` doesn't get converted to <, so it shows `&lt;b>**bold text**&lt;/b>`

Another line I tried is the following:

```
<![CDATA[<b><b>bold text</b></b>]]>
```

Unfortunately it didn't work either, just shows **bold text**.

The reason I need to do this is simply to include written CRDATA reference, or cheat sheet, into an application that supports CRDATA. I have since solved the issue as outlined in my answer to this question, I used a zero-width space to create fake formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright i found an answer I added a zero-width space to one of the `<b>` and `</b>` tags like this `<*space*​b><b>bold text</*space*b></​b>`, the output is this <​b>**bold text**</​b> as you can see it works
copied it from here https://invisible-characters.com/